# XNA: How do I match Spritebatch View/Projection Matrices with BasicEffect Matrices?

Tags: xna, matrix, projection, viewport, view

I'm rendering a bunch of 2D content using `SpriteBatch`es to a default XNA viewport. A simple 2D camera is used to move around the scene, which generates a transformation matrix passed to each `SpriteBatch.Begin()`-call.

I want to draw custom polygons on top of my `SpriteBatch`es, which I'm doing via `DrawIndexedPrimitives` (straightforward, as well). I'm using a `BasicEffect` to shade them.

How can I best match up the `SpriteBatch`'s implicit view and projection matrices with the `BasicEffect`'s matrices? Currently, I create the matrices for the `Effect` from scratch, using the `Viewport`'s properties. How can I get around this? Can I access the `Viewport`'s matrices and pass them into the `BasicEffect`?

So far, Google has come up empty on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a DirectX library called the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) which is a porting of the underlying XNA code written by people who were members of the XNA team. Below is the code relevant to you question.

### [SpriteBatch.cpp](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/SpriteBatch.cpp)

---

**PrepareForRendering()**

```
// Set the transform matrix.
XMMATRIX transformMatrix = (mRotation == DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_UNSPECIFIED)
                           ? mTransformMatrix
                           : ( mTransformMatrix * GetViewportTransform(deviceContext, mRotation) );

mContextResources->constantBuffer.SetData(deviceContext, transformMatrix);
```

**GetViewportTransform()**

```
// Generates a viewport transform matrix for rendering sprites using x-right y-down screen pixel coordinates.
XMMATRIX SpriteBatch::Impl::GetViewportTransform(_In_ ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, DXGI_MODE_ROTATION rotation )
{
    // Look up the current viewport.
    if ( !mSetViewport )
    {
        UINT viewportCount = 1;

        deviceContext->RSGetViewports(&viewportCount, &mViewPort);

        if (viewportCount != 1)
            throw std::exception("No viewport is set");
    }
    
    // Compute the matrix.
    float xScale = (mViewPort.Width  > 0) ? 2.0f / mViewPort.Width  : 0.0f;
    float yScale = (mViewPort.Height > 0) ? 2.0f / mViewPort.Height : 0.0f;

    switch( rotation )
    {
    case DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_ROTATE90:
        return XMMATRIX
        (
             0,       -yScale,  0,  0,
             -xScale, 0,        0,  0,
             0,       0,        1,  0,
             1,       1,        0,  1
        );

    case DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_ROTATE270:
        return XMMATRIX
        (
             0,       yScale,   0,  0,
             xScale,  0,        0,  0,
             0,       0,        1,  0,
            -1,      -1,        0,  1
        );

    case DXGI_MODE_ROTATION_ROTATE180:
        return XMMATRIX
        (
            -xScale,  0,       0,  0,
             0,       yScale,  0,  0,
             0,       0,       1,  0,
             1,      -1,       0,  1
        );

    default:
        return XMMATRIX
        (
             xScale,  0,       0,  0,
             0,      -yScale,  0,  0,
             0,       0,       1,  0,
            -1,       1,       0,  1
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: DirectX Tool Kit source is available on [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).